# How to delete rows from a data.frame, based on an external list, using R?

Tags: r, dataframe

This might be an easy question but i still need some help for using R.

I have a data.frame (main_data), lets say..

```
NAMES   AGE     LOC
Jyo     23      Hyd
Abid    27      Kar
Ras     24      Pun
Poo     25      Goa
Sus     28      Kar
```

I wish to remove a few rows based on a list of names. So lets say I have another list of table as follows:

```
NAMES_list
Jyo
Ras
Poo
```

So based on this list, if any of the names match to my above "main_data" table, then I would like to remove the whole row contianing them, so the result should be as follows

```
NAMES   AGE     LOC
Abid    27      Kar
Sus     28      Kar
```

Can anyone help me how to achive this using R? 
Thanks in advance.. :)

Comment: I had this same task, but had names in format "Last, First".  For those of you with similar formatting, you may find that removing spaces from names may be necessary to get code in answers below to work.                                             `gsub(" ","",x)` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Use `%in%`:

```
main_data2 <- main_data[ ! main_data$NAMES %in% NAMES_list, ]
```

Answer (score 13):

If, by chance, you actually have a [`data.table`](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/) (as opposed to a `data.frame`), and your `data.table` has a `key`, you can use the not join idiom

```
library(data.table)
dat <- as.data.table(read.table(text="
NAMES   AGE     LOC
Jyo     23      Hyd
Abid    27      Kar
Ras     24      Pun
Poo     25      Goa
Sus     28      Kar", 
stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header=TRUE))

setkey(dat, NAMES)

to.remove <- c("Jyo","Ras","Poo")
dat[-dat[to.remove, which=TRUE]]
#   NAMES AGE LOC
#1:  Abid  27 Kar
#2:   Sus  28 Kar
```

Of course, the other [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13012659/967840) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13012618/967840) would also work on a `data.table`, but this should be more efficient.

---

**Edit**

As of data.table version 1.8.3, the "!" prefix can be used for "not-joins" (see [NEWS](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/NEWS?view=markup&revision=713&root=datatable)).

```
dat[!to.remove]
   NAMES AGE LOC
1:  Abid  27 Kar
2:   Sus  28 Kar
```

Comment: +1 We really need proper not joins working don't we: `dat[-to.remove]`. It's actually quite easy to implement internally but I just haven't got to it yet :( It's [FR#1384](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=1384&group_id=240&atid=978).

Answer (score 9):

Replicate your data:

```
dat <- read.table(text="
NAMES   AGE     LOC
Jyo     23      Hyd
Abid    27      Kar
Ras     24      Pun
Poo     25      Goa
Sus     28      Kar", 
stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header=TRUE)

remove <- c("Jyo", "Ras", "Poo")
```

Simple subsetting:

```
dat[!dat$NAMES %in% remove, ]
  NAMES AGE LOC
2  Abid  27 Kar
5   Sus  28 Kar
```

---

Here's how it works: Use a combination of `!` negation and `%in%` to return a logical vector that indicates the rows to keep:

```
!dat$NAMES %in% remove
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

I remember being surprised by this construct the first time I saw it. Why is it that `!dat$NAMES` returns anything useful? Well, of course the insight is that the infix operator `%in%` gets evaluated first, so the `!` is simply a logical NOT operator.

Comment: ...and it gets evaluated first because it has [precedence](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/Syntax.html) over `%any%`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use also use `match` if there are unique values in your main_data$NAMES

```
NAMES_list <- c("Jyo","Ras","Poo")
main_data <- main_data[-match(NAMES_list,main_data$NAMES),]
main_data
  NAMES AGE LOC
2  Abid  27 Kar
5   Sus  28 Kar
```

It will remove the rows that exactly matches your NAMES_list with main_data$NAMES.

Comment: what does `-match()` means (especially the minus)