# Remove a range in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to exclude some rows from a datatable based on, let's say, days and month - excluding for example summer holidays, that always begin for example 15th of June and end the 15th of next month. I can extract those days based on Date, but as as.Date function is awfully slow to operate with, I have separate integer columns for Month and Day and I want to do it using only them.

It is easy to select the given entries by

```
DT[Month==6][Day>=15]
DT[Month==7][Day<=15]
```

Is there any way how to make "difference" of the two `data.tables` (the original ones and the ones I selected). (Why not subset? Maybe I am missing something simple, but I don't want to exclude days like 10/6, 31/7.)

I am aware of a way to do it with join, but only day by day

```
setkey(DT, Month, Day)
DT[-DT[J(Month,Day), which= TRUE]]
```

Can anyone help how to solve it in more general way?

Comment: Good question. You'll likely be interested in the answers and discussion that resulted from the same question when it was asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319083/how-do-i-do-a-negative-nomatch-inverse-search-in-data-table/12319774#12319774

Comment: And there was [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13013289/1281189) just a little while ago

Comment: Hmm, yes, that is interesting, but for me the problem is, that I cannot do negative match in this way, because I try to do subset based on two columns... :-/ The problem I need to do complement to intersection...

Comment: @tomaskrehlik Why not `subset`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great question. I've edited the question title to match the question.

A simple approach avoiding `as.Date` which reads nicely :

```
DT[!(Month*100L+Day) %between% c(0615L,0715L)]
```

That's probably fast enough in many cases. If you have a lot of different ranges, then you may want to step up a gear :

```
DT[,mmdd:=Month*100L+Day]
from = DT[J(0615),mult="first",which=TRUE]
to = DT[J(0715),mult="first",which=TRUE]
DT[-(from:to)]
```

That's a bit long and error prone because it's DIY. So one idea is that a `list` column in an `i` table would represent a range query ([FR#203](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?group_id=240&atid=978&func=detail&aid=203), like a binary search `%between%`). Then a *not-join* (also not yet implemented, [FR#1384](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?group_id=240&atid=978&func=detail&aid=1384)) could be combined with the list column range query to do exactly what you asked :

```
setkey(DT,mmdd)
DT[-J(list(0615,0715))]
```

That would extend to multiple different ranges, or the same range for many different ids, in the usual way; i.e., more rows added to `i`.

Comment: And what about "negative select"? I mean something that would have syntax something like `!DT[Month==6][Day>=15]` and would produce the original dataset without the selected entries?

Comment: @tomaskrehlik Huh? That's what my answer answers, doesn't it? Are you defining a new term _negative-select_ different to _not-join_?  Another way is just : `DT[!(Month==6 & Day>=15)]`.

Comment: yes, sorry, the answer gets the job done, of course. The comment was a mere suggestion for feature that I think would read nicely and be extremely easy to understand.

Comment: @tomaskrehlik Is your suggestion syntax like `!DT[Month==6][Day>=15]`? This can't work because `!` of a dataset makes no sense. The compound `[Month==6][Day>=15]` is missing the raison d'etre for everything being inside one `[...]` if possible.  No `j` in the first `[Month==6]` means all columns will be subset, to be passed to the second `[Day>=15]`. `data.table` wants you to combine things together and stick the _select_ query (or _negative-select_) as `i` inside `[...]`, not outside. Then it can make optimizations under the hood for you.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13013289/1281189), you might try something like

```
# Sample data
DT <- data.table(Month = sample(c(1,3:12), 100, replace = TRUE),
  Day = sample(1:30, 100, replace = TRUE), key = "Month,Day")

# Dates that you want to exclude
excl <- as.data.table(rbind(expand.grid(6, 15:30), expand.grid(7, 1:15)))

DT[-na.omit(DT[excl, which = TRUE])]
```

If your data contain at least one entry for each day you want to exclude, `na.omit` might not be required.

Comment: Thx, I can actually loop (omg, he is looping!!! yes!) over the `Join` up in my code, I was hoping for something more general/user friendly.

Comment: @tomaskrehlik, It looks like a more general / user friendly method is on Matthew Dowle's to-do list, as he mentions in his comment in that answer I linked to. If looping over the join works for you, that's fine!

Comment: ahh, I didn't read that comment! That was what I was looking for, so it does't seem to exist. Thanks!